# Set product price with multiple websites

Tags: product, magento-1.8, php, api, price

I have setup my Magento with 2 websites, with ID 1 and 4, and one store for each website.

Default website is 1.

My product has a Default price.

How can I set programmatically a price for website 4 without touching website 1?

See what I have tried so far:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$product->setWebsiteId(4)->setPrice($newPrice)->save();
```

Unfortunately the code above leaves unchanged the price for website 4, and overrides Default price for website 1 with `$newPrice`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set the StoreId, not the websiteId. Just needed to choose a store belonging to the desired website:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$product->setStoreId(1) -> setPrice($price1) ->save() ;
$product->setStoreId(9) -> setPrice($price9) ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

For This you need below code

```
<?php
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->load($Id); 

 $product->setPrice('Yor price');
 $product->save();
 unset($product);
 ?>
```

Comment: hmm I think you did not get the idea so Just prepare answer for you Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like this solution has changed the Visibility status to all products!!

Comment: not sure for that but if it will change then set them again

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing exactly this on the latest version (1.9.3.1) and the only way i could get it working was to set and unset the store id's as below, this was so i could post a different price in store 2 vs all the other stores (10 on this system)

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(2);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $this->p_sku);
if ($product) {
    $product->setData('price', 19.99);
    $product->save();
}
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```